# Pipelight was working with chrome, but it stopped once I restarted

Tags: pipelight

I restarted my computer and went into terminal and enabled pipelight. However, when I try to play a netflix video (With user agent switcher activated) it asks me to install silverlight? I dont know what happened, it worked fine when I first installed and ran it. Any ideas?

I was using Firefox 15 with user agent switcher on chrome, the IE options lead to an error saying active x needs to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your user agent switcher is set to that you are using Windows and that you have not set your user agent to Internet Explorer. Also, make sure that Pipelight is updated. Also, enable Silverlight by typing in a terminal `sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight`